# Query using related name in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've two models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Profile(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='profiles')
    image = models.ForeignKey(Media, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #more attributes
```

I've user's id and I want to get his image.

```
user = User.objects.get(id=id)
image = user.profiles.image
```

This is throwing error. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that your User to Profile relation is many-to-one, so when you call `user.profiles` it is creating a queryset of possibly many Profile objects and not just one. The queryset of profiles does not have an image attribute.

You need to do one of two things, either:

a) Extract a single profile from your profiles queryset, e.g. `user.profiles.first()` - note that if you have multiple profiles then this will just get the first one in the set by whichever order_by the profile model has.

b) Set the User/Profile relationship to one-to-one rather than many-to-one by using a `models.OneToOneField`. This will allow you to directly access the profile with `user.profile`

Once you have direct access to the profile object, you can call the image attribute that it has.